# Dojo lang.replace - how to provide default value, instead of 'undefined'?

Tags: javascript, dojo, replace

Dojo `lang.replace()` replaces the undefined placeholders with `undefined` text. Is it possible to define the default value within placeholder?

Let's say I want to have the following placeholder:

```
<div class="message">The query returned {result.rows:0} rows</div>
```

The placeholder will be replaced with the numbers of rows returned, but when the variable `rows` is not available (for exapmle, the result contains error message) it will be replaced with 0.

Answer (score 3):

There are two approaches you can consider.  The first is to mixin the `results` object with defaults before passing it into the `replace` function.

```
var defaults = {
    rows: 0
};
var data = lang.mixin(lang.clone(defaults), result);

lang.replace(template, data);
```

The second approach is instead of passing a data object, pass a function that knows how to default the value when missing.

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/_base/lang.html#with-a-function

Comment: Been looking for this answer for a while, ive been using string.replace to remove nulls after running dojo.replace from the returning JSON...